# For-Comprehension Future with exceptions

Tags: scala

I have two Future and I want to recover exceptions on one of them :

```
def getId(): Future[Either[Exception, Id]] = ...
def result(): Future[Result] = ...
```

I have try something like this:

```
for {
  id <- getId()
  r <- result(id, param, param)
} yield {
  r
} recover {
  case e => println(e.getMessage)
}
```

Someone can help me?

Many thanks before.

Comment: Futures already encapsulate exceptions. Why use `Either`?

Answer (score 0):

You should recover at the val being processed rather than at the for. The below code sets id and r to 0 if an exception is thrown.

```
for {
  id = getId()
  id.recover {
    case e => {
      println(e.getMessage)
      0
    }
  }
  r = result(id, param, param)
} yield r.recover {
    case e => {
      println(e.getMessage)
      0
    }
  }
```